# AWS SDK get session token for rbac token

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-net

I have an API and other services configured and secured via AWS. We have applied a RBAC style permission system to allow/deny access to resources using groups in Cognito and federated-identities.

When a user logs into to the system, they get a JWT token listing the cognio:roles they have access to, and can use these to perform different actions by requesting a temporary session token for that resource.

I currently have a Angular website, which is working as expected and once the user has logged in, is able to request the session tokens like this:

```
buildCognitoCreds(idTokenJwt: string, customRoleArn: string) {
    let url = 'cognito-idp.' + CognitoUtil._REGION.toLowerCase() + '.amazonaws.com/' + CognitoUtil._USER_POOL_ID;

    let logins: CognitoIdentity.LoginsMap = {};
    logins[url] = idTokenJwt;
    let params = {
        IdentityPoolId: CognitoUtil._IDENTITY_POOL_ID, /* required */
        Logins: logins,
        CustomRoleArn: customRoleArn
    };
    let serviceConfigs: awsservice.ServiceConfigurationOptions = {};

    let creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params, serviceConfigs);
    console.log('Creds for role: ' + customRoleArn + ':', creds);
    this.setCognitoCreds(creds);
    return creds;
}
```

I am now trying to do the same in .net as we have a number of desktop and mobile (Xamarin) app that need to access the AWS resources / api.

I have followed the AWS blog here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cognitoauthentication-extension-library-developer-preview/ 
and am able to authenticate my users against my cognito user pool.

I am now stuck, as how to get the session tokens for a specific role the user has permissions for - I have tried using the following:

```
var credentials = _authenticationService.User.GetCognitoAWSCredentials(
                "us-east-1:ef964b45-939e-4ef3-91c6-xxxxxxxxxxxx", // Identity pool ID
                RegionEndpoint.USEast1 // Region
            );

            var url = "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx";
            var logins = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            logins.Add(url, _authenticationService.AuthenticationResult.IdToken);

            GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest request = new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest();
            request.IdentityId = "us-east-1:ef964b45-939e-4ef3-91c6-xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            request.Logins = logins;
            request.CustomRoleArn = customRoleArn;

            var c = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            var test = c.GetIdentityPoolRolesAsync("us-east-1:ef964b45-939e-4ef3-91c6-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx").Result;

            var result = c.GetCredentialsForIdentityAsync(request).Result;

            Console.WriteLine(result.Credentials.AccessKeyId);
```

However every time I do I get a: `Amazon.CognitoIdentity.Model.NotAuthorizedException` with the message: 
`The ambiguous role mapping rules for: cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx denied this request.`

From tracing through the code, and testing it seems that I somehow need to specify the CustomRoleArn to use when getting the cognito was credentials from the Cognito User, otherwise token based rule in the cognito federated identity will return a deny response. - But I can't work out how to do this in the AWS .net SDK......

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this problem.  Mine is similar.